# Preserve damaged TrueCrypt partition before repairs

Tags: truecrypt

I've got a TC partition damaged by Windows installation. In its inifinite wisdom Windows thinks it is okay to use random "unoccupied" HDD plugged in PC as it sees fit and puts a small boot partition here even when told to be installed elsewhere, thus overwriting TC header and most (or all) of encrypted volume metadata. I've managed to mount partition with TC by using spare footer, and will proceed to fiddle with different repair/data extractions tools to get several important files from there.

Before I start, I would like to preserve entire damaged partition in some way so if any of tools make things worse I could rollback to current state. If possible, I would also like to convert this partition to TC container file, so rolling back would be as simple as just copying it. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to preserve a damaged volume is to use a sector-by-sector image-based using advanced backup software like Acronis Backup & Recovery.  It is file-agnostic and just cares about backing up every sector.  Bear in mind you must configure it to these settings.  Alternatively you could by a disk drive replicator and clone the drive using the replicator to another drive.

Once backed up, attempt decryption.

Hope this helps!